# Python/Flask - Print response value from nested JSON

Tags: python, flask

How can I output the value of 'Number#en' from my response? I am struggling to understand the nested structure. Thanks

**Response from my api**

```
  {
    'count': 1, 'total': 1, 
    
    'data': [
    
    {'id': '6a3d7026-43f3-67zt-9211-99dfc6fee82e', 
     'name': 'test',  
     'properties': {'Description#en': 'test', 'Number#en': '20934120'}}],
```

**what I have trying to print the value**

```
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    data_text = json.loads(response.text)
    
    print(data_text[data]['properties.Number#en'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data_text['data'] is a list of dictionary so to access the **Number#en**, you should use

```
data_text['data'][0]['properties']['Number#en']
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. I am receiving the following error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: If you don't get the data field back in the response, the above won't work. You will need to explicitly check whether **data** is null or not and if the value it holds is a list. Could you provide the output **data_text['data']** when you get the error please?